# deleteObject doesn't work in Realm

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, realm

Here is my code and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong . I'm doing as it says in the document 
http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.91.1/#deleting-objects

```
       // Delete Current Object
        RLMRealm *realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm;

        [realm beginWriteTransaction];
        EBooks *eBookdb = [[EBooks alloc]init];
        eBookdb.eBook_ID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.eBookID];
        eBookdb.status = @"canceled";
        [EBooks createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withObject:eBookdb];

        [realm commitWriteTransaction];

        //=> break point here before crash      

        [realm beginWriteTransaction];
        [realm deleteObject:eBookdb];
        [realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

and the app crashes after the breakpoint with the following error

> 'Can only delete an object from the Realm it belongs to.'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to delete the standalone `EBooks` object, rather than the one persisted in the Realm. If you change your code to the following, it ought to work:

```
// Delete Current Object


RLMRealm *realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm;

[realm beginWriteTransaction];
EBooks *eBookdb = [[EBooks alloc]init];
eBookdb.eBook_ID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.eBookID];
eBookdb.status = @"canceled";
eBookdb = [EBooks createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withObject:eBookdb];

[realm commitWriteTransaction];  

[realm beginWriteTransaction];
[realm deleteObject:eBookdb];
[realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

Comment: This is my current code http://pastebin.com/N8VhTG7M

But I'm getting new a error now ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Index is out of bounds.'***

Comment: I'm sorry that error was cause due to different problem . thanks :D